# Array position difference beetween two elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I've got this array:
[1,2,3,4,5]

I want to determine the position difference between two elements, but in a "rotation" mode.

Example:
I have 3 and I want to know how far is 2, I do a 3.position - 2.position, and I've got 1.

But, if I have 5, and I want to know the position difference beetween 5.position and 1.position, with the precedent difference, I will have 5-1=4, and because there is array rotation, I want 1.

Do you have an idea of how I can do that ? (I work in Javascript)

EDIT:
Here is a draw that can explain clearer what I want to do

EDIT 2: Better draw
[image: Draw circular]

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What exactly are you trying to do here? This would be insightful to know and would help us answer your question.

Comment: @thijs: figure out the shortest distance between two array elements, pretending that the array is a circle, so that there's invisible `...,5,1,2,3,...`

Comment: Ok, sorry for my english. I will draw it, it will be clearer.

Comment: So I assume that at the start you have an array with numbers (perhaps known, perhaps unknown values..) and you have two values of which you do now know the index yet. You want to determine the shortest distance between these two elements in the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculate both the distance within the array, and the distance when wrapping around, and use the smallest.

This code uses `pos1` and `pos2` as the index of the items in the array `arr`, and assumes that `pos1 < pos2`:

```
var distance = Math.min(pos2 - pos1, pos1 + arr.length - pos2);
```

Comment: It works great ! Thanks !
I will test it about performance, because I will probably use it about 25 times per second... I will give some feedback about that

Comment: This function will perform absolutely fine being called 25 times per second. Also, there is not really a (significantly) faster way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Guffa's answer is far more succinct and simple, but I already wrote the JSfiddle so I'll share.

```
var testArray = [1,2,3,4,5];

function getShortestDistance(element1Name, element2Name){
    var result = -1;
    var position1 = testArray.indexOf(element1Name);
    var position2 = testArray.indexOf(element2Name);
    // The distance should never be greater than half of the array length, half being defined as integer division by 2
    var maxDistance = Math.floor(testArray.length/2);
    if(Math.abs(position1 - position2) >= maxDistance){
        result = Math.abs(testArray.length - Math.abs(position1 - position2));
    }
    else{
        result = Math.abs(position1-position2);
    }
    alert('position1 is ' + position1);
    alert('position2 is ' + position2);
    alert('Distance is ' + result);
}

getShortestDistance(2,3); // Will return 1
getShortestDistance(1,4); // Will return 2
```

Here's the JSFiddle in case you want to modify it: http://jsfiddle.net/u71vbeau/16/